# Using same button again

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating an app to play audio. The layout is such that I have to give buttons with the same function, look etc in different places within the same activity.

I was wondering if there is a way by which I define the button (image button in this case) once and then just use the same definition in the layout file each time.

Comment: Yes, you can define a state variable to save what state the button is in currently and then check for this state in click listener and perform action accordingly.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want to store the layout properties of the button and then just use that abridged definition of the button in different places of my layout, rather than defining the button in <ImageButton> tags repeatedly throughout the layout

Comment: Yeah I did..:)...Let me use the answer section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use the `<include>` tag. In other words:

1. create a new xml file containing the imageButton with your custom
   styling
2. include that layout in other layouts files

More info at:
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible solution is to create a [Custom View](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).  With these views, you can define Java code and nested elements that can be written and stylized once, and reused wherever needed.  This would be similar to Lino's answer, but allow you to reuse Java code as well and in some cases be a little more concise.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solution

1-Create a Button Style and Use it in your layout e.g.

create style in res/values/styles.xml like this

`<style name="ImageButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/image</item>
</style>`

then use  it in your layout like this
`<ImageButon style="@style/ImageButtonStyle"/>`

2- create a new xml file and define your image button there like this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>`

now use include tag to include it in your layout
`<include layout="@layout/my_image_button">`